# Python List in Java

Tags: java, python, xml-rpc

I'm using XMLRPC calls from java to python.

So my server in python has these remote method and use apache xmlrpc lib in java to make the calls.

So i always prefered to use Dictionary to return from the calls. Cause when i used dictionary, Object data type in java, was directly printing my valueset returned from python. Then i used Map to iterate.

Now i 've to return list in one of the methods.
I couldn convert Object to List/ArrayList/HashMap.

need help... How to convert Python List in Java?

Sample Output:

```
{hello=1, list=[Ljava.lang.Object;@1ba9f7}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the conversion worked correctly - `[Ljava.lang.Object;@1ba9f7` is the default way that a Java **array** (not List) of Objects is printed out. Not very helpful, but there you go...

You could convert it to a Java **List** using `Arrays.asList(mylist)`. See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Or try printing out the items in the array using:

```
for (Object obj: myArray)
{ 
   System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Comment: Object res_lst =client.execute("getme",params);
    List<Object> l=Arrays.asList(res_lst);
    System.out.println(l.get(0));
Still i get the same value.. [Ljava.lang.Object;@115e891

Comment: Object[] rl =(Object[]) client.execute("getme",p);
        for (Object obj: rl)
        { 
           System.out.println(obj);
        }